# what is the meaning of a set $G$(cyclic Group)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

A group G is called cyclic if there is an element $a\in G$ such that the cyclic
subgroup generated by $a$ is the entire group $G$.Then

Now  my confusion is  that which one is  correct ?

$G = \{a^n: \text{for all }n \in \mathbb{ Z}\}$.

$G = \{a^n: \text{for some }n \in \mathbb{ Z}\}$.

**My thinking**  :If $G = \{a^n: \text{for some }n \in \mathbb{ Z}\}$,then $G$ will be a subgroup of $G$   this appears to contradict the definition of cyclic group .So $G = \{a^n: \text{for some }n \in \mathbb{ Z}\}$. is not correct

I think $G = \{a^n: \text{for all }n \in \mathbb{ Z}\}$  is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, none of the options make sense. It should be$$G=\{a^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\};$$which means that $G=\{\ldots,a^{-2},a^{-1},e_G,a,a^2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: ... which is doubtlessly what Jasmine was trying to express with her first expression. The remaining difference is not about group theory but about how to use the set builder notation correctly.

Comment: you are  right @Troposphere I thought the same thing.

Comment: Adding to this answer: Actually, $\{a^n : n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a shorthand for $\{g \in G : g=a^n \textrm{ for some } n \in \mathbb Z\}$, or $\{g \in G : \textrm{there exists $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that } g = a^n\}$, or $\{g \in G : (\exists n \in \mathbb Z^+) \ g=a^n\}$, the one that you likes more. As another example, the set of even integers $\{n \in \mathbb Z : (\exists k \in \mathbb Z) \ n=2k\}$ is written more commonly as $\{2k : k \in \mathbb Z\}$.